# Service class with db context

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have implemented service which working with db context. I am using entity framework and I do not need repositories because logic is quite simple.

I want to keep simple logic but clean approach.
One problem I have is when I want to call service method 2 times in same service instance. I will get context dispose exception. 
this is not problem in my case because for now I do not have case like that.
But maybe you have idea for better solution.

my code:

```
using Common.Configurations;
using Common.Container;
using Common.Factory;
using Common.Helpers;
using Common.Services;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using RemoteManager.EntityFramework;
using Common.Entities;

namespace RemoteManagerApi.Services
{
    public class MachineService : IMachineService
    {
        private readonly IOptions<ApplicationConfiguration> applicationConfiguration;
        private readonly ILogger<MachineService> logger;
        private readonly IMachineCleaner machineCleaner;
        private readonly IFileContainer fileContainer;
        private readonly RemoteManagerContext context;

        public MachineService(RemoteManagerContext context, IFileContainerFactory fileContainerFactory, IOptions<ApplicationConfiguration> applicationConfiguration, IMachineCleaner machineCleaner, ILogger<MachineService> logger)
        {
            this.fileContainer = fileContainerFactory.CreateContainer();
            this.applicationConfiguration = applicationConfiguration;
            this.logger = logger;
            this.machineCleaner = machineCleaner;
            this.context = context;
        }

        public async Task<MachineConfiguration> Add(MachineConfiguration machine)
        {
            try
            {
                await this.fileContainer.CreateDirectory(machine.SessionFolder);
                logger.LogInformation($"Start  {nameof(MachineService)}:{nameof(this.Add)}");
                using (var db = this.context)
                {
                    var res = db.MachineConfigurations.Add(machine);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return await Task.FromResult(res);
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                logger.LogError($"Error  {nameof(MachineService)}:{nameof(this.Add)}");
                throw;
            }
        }

        public async Task<bool> Delete(int id)
        {
            try
            {
                logger.LogInformation($"Start  {nameof(MachineService)}:{nameof(this.Delete)}");
                using (var db = this.context)
                {
                    var machineConfiguration = db.MachineConfigurations.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Id == id);
                    var isDeleted = db.MachineConfigurations.Remove(machineConfiguration);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return await Task.FromResult(true);
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                logger.LogError($"Error  {nameof(MachineService)}:{nameof(this.Delete)}");
                throw;
            }
        }

        public async Task<MachineConfiguration> Get(int id)
        {
            try
            {
                logger.LogInformation($"Start  {nameof(MachineService)}:{nameof(this.Get)}");
                using (var db = this.context)
                {
                    var machineConfiguration = db.MachineConfigurations.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Id == id);
                    return await Task.FromResult(machineConfiguration);
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                logger.LogError($"Error  {nameof(MachineService)}:{nameof(this.Get)}");
                throw;
            }
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<MachineConfiguration>> GetAll()
        {
            try
            {
                logger.LogInformation($"Start  {nameof(MachineService)}:{nameof(this.GetAll)}");
                using (var db = this.context)
                {
                    var machineConfigurations = db.MachineConfigurations.ToList();
                    return await Task.FromResult(machineConfigurations);
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                logger.LogError($"Error  {nameof(MachineService)}:{nameof(this.GetAll)}");
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use a single unit of work class to read and update database(unit of work design pattern).

Comment: Unit of work goes together with the Repository pattern. All that is unnecessarily complicated in my case.

Comment: An EF `DbContext` *is* a unit of work - it encapsulates a transaction. Wrapping it with a full-blown UoW+Repository pattern isn't just overkill, it's outright wrong IMO. And it wouldn't solve the "who's responsible for disposing the context" problem.

Comment: Also... if you look closely at the class' public interface, it definitely looks like a generic repository anyway.

Comment: Unit of work and repository pattern can be useful if we want to decouple data access and entity framework. For example if in future we need to replace entity framework with something else. In my case they are strongly coupled. But as I said, I don't need that.

Comment: That's the typical argument, and it's utter BS. Sure you've decoupled data access and EF, but then when you swap EF for something else you *still* need to rewrite/reimplement your entire DAL, so.. what gives? IMO what you have here is perfectly acceptable. The only itchy spot might be with mocking the concrete `RemoteManagerContext` type for unit tests, but then, seems to me `IMachineService` is doing a fine job of abstracting data access from the rest of the application.

Comment: You can have both implementations (2 class libraries, EF and ADO.NET). You can switch from EF to ADO.NET and after some time back to EF. Also  you can work on DataAccess ADO.NET library and someone else in mean time can work on service classes with old data access(EF) without any conflict.

Comment: Exactly - and as far as I can see, nothing prevents you from implementing `IMachineService` *right now* using ADO.NET, and then configuring your IoC to inject `AdoMachineService` instead of this `MachineService`: your `IMachineService` interface *is* in the role of the repository here, hence further abstracting with IoW+Repository being completely overboard.

Comment: Ok, I see your point. I can't argue with that :)

Answer (score 7):

You're injecting a disposable resource (`context`) - this means *someone else* is creating it (which is excellent BTW), and *that someone else* should therefore be responsible for disposing the context.

But your code is wrapping `context` accesses in a `using` block, which is going to call `Dispose` on that `context` when execution leaves the `using` scope.

Remove the `using` scopes - it's not *this class'* job to dispose the context. If you're using an IoC container for dependency injection, it's the container that's owning the instances, and therefore it's the container's responsibility to dispose them. If you're not using an IoC container, then whoever is `new`ing up the `RemoteManagerContext` is the owner that needs to dispose it.

Comment: I am using IoC in Startup: "services.AddTransient<RemoteManagerContext>(_ => new RemoteManagerContext(connectionString));". DbContext is unmenaged resource. Can I be sure that is Disposed ?

Comment: `DbContext` itself *is* a managed resource, it's just `IDisposable`. I don't know which DI framework you're using, but with Ninject the transient scope (which is the default) does not handle `IDisposable` dependencies. With Ninject I'd bind it `.InCallScope()` or, if this is a web/MVC application, `.InRequestScope()` so as to get one instance per request. If you *really* want to be 100% certain that your container is calling `Dispose`, you could make a thin wrapper for the context, implement `IDisposable`, and place a breakpoint in your `Dispose` implementation, or just TRACE-log the disposal.

Comment: Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection. I am working on ASP.NET Core project.

Comment: Per [this page](https://docs.asp.net/projects/api/en/latest/autoapi/Microsoft/Extensions/DependencyInjection/), it seems you need to work with some `IServiceScope` - again I don't know the specifics, but it seems it's just a matter of properly configuring the IoC container and your resources will be disposed as they should.